# Fluent NHibernate Join mapping to Joined table

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have entity like:

```
class Doc 
{
public virtual int Id {get;set;}
public virtual int Code {get;set;}
}
```

where `Id` is identity.
And `Code` is placed in another table. to get `Code` I use next SQL statement:

```
Select Distinct A.CODE from DOCLIST D Left Join DOCSLINKS  DL On DL.TODOC_ID=D.DOC_ID
Left Join ARTICLES A On DL.ART_ID=A.ART_ID  Where D.DOC_ID=*ourid*
```

where `ourid` is `Id` of our entity

The map of Doc class is:

```
public class DocMap : ClassMap<Doc>
    {
        public DocMap()
        {
            Table("DOCLIST");
            Id(x =>x.Id).Column("DOC_ID").GeneratedBy.Custom<NHibernate.Id.TriggerIdentityGenerator>(); 

            //HOW TO MAP CODE?
        }
     }
```

I try to use `Formula`:

```
Map(x => x.Code).Formula("(Select Distinct A.CODE from DOCLIST D Left Join DOCSLINKS  DL On DL.TODOC_ID=D.DOC_ID
Left Join ARTICLES A On DL.ART_ID=A.ART_ID  Where D.DOC_ID=Id)").Not.Update();
```

But I handle an exception  `ORA-00904 : "DOC0_"."ID": invalid identifier` with message:

```
could not load an entity: [Doc#1562][SQL: SELECT doc0_.DOC_ID as DOC1_3_0_, (Select Distinct A.OKP_CODE from DOCLIST D  Left join  DOCSLINKS DL ON DL.TODOC_ID=D.DOC_ID Left join ARTICLES A ON DL.ART_ID=A.ART_ID  Where D.DOC_ID=doc0_.Id) as formula0_0_ FROM DOCLIST doc0_ WHERE doc0_.DOC_ID=?]
```

Can anybody help me to map `Code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that we should change the select. It should not be using the current table `DOCLIST` *(which is alreaedy used for mapping the root class `Doc` .. `Table("DOCLIST")`)*

```
// current select
(SELECT Distinct A.CODE 
 FROM DOCLIST D 
 Left Join DOCSLINKS DL On DL.TODOC_ID=D.DOC_ID
 Left Join ARTICLES  A  On DL.ART_ID=A.ART_ID  
 Where D.DOC_ID=Id)
```

This should do the job (or with some adjustments)

```
(SELECT Distinct A.CODE 
 FROM DOCSLINKS DL
 Left Join ARTICLES  A  On DL.ART_ID=A.ART_ID  
 Where DL.TODOC_ID = DOC_ID) // DOC_ID should be column on current table
```

We are already having access to table `DOCLIST` (the current table). We just have to SELECT from other tables, while using our ID in the wwhere clause to filter DOCSLINKS:

```
Where DL.TODOC_ID = DOC_ID // DOC_ID will be used from current table
```